# Retrieving values of sublists without using other lists

Tags: python

I am trying to get the value of the i sublist and then i'm indexing in order to find the 1st and 2nd values in that sublist.

However I cannot index by i, since it is a list.
How can I achieve this output?

```
forSale = [[b, 50],[m,60],[t,90]]

if choice ==3:
    i = len(forSale)
    for i in forSale:
        print forSale[i][0], ": ",forSale[i][1]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: print all values of the list/sublists in the following format:
b : 50 
m : 60
t : 90

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to print the values of the sublist, then directly use `i` , which points to the sublists in each iteration. Example -

```
forSale = [['b', 50],['m',60],['t',90]]

if choice ==3:
    for i in forSale:
        print '{0} : {1}'.format(i[0],i[1])
```

Comment: The line `i = len(forSale)` should be eliminated.  I realize the OP had it there, but it just confuses matters.

Answer (score 0):

You can venture in to list comprehensions to solve this one.

Firstly, change your variable naming to this instead:

`forSale` => `for_sale`

Read up on [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for the style guide.

```
' '.join(["{}:{}".format(i[0],i[1]) for i in for_sale])
```

The `' '.join(` part will convert back to a string with a space between each word. The inside of the `[ ]` is pretty much iterating over the array, grabbing the first and second index from the sublist and placing a `:` between them.

If they have to be printed on individual lines then you are just gonna do this:

```
for i in for_sale:
    print("{}:{}".format(i[0], i[1]))
```